# Ethereum Wallet Password Recovery

Tags: ether, wallets, mist, recovery

I recently moved some ETH to the Ethereum Wallet, but I must have committed a typo by accident when creating the password, as I cannot send it from the account now.

Can someone please help me understand how to use 'pyethrecover-master' as I have no clue how to.

https://github.com/burjorjee/pyethrecover