# Password in my Ethereum Wallet lost

Tags: password

How do I recover it? Am I SOL (sh*t out of luck)? I could have sworn it was the same as before. I've made 5 wallets all with the same password and for some reason, this isn't working.

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1855/ethereum-wallet-password-recovery and http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-can-i-recover-or-reset-a-lost-wallet-password or click on the password tag below this question.